# generating content based on subdomain

Tags: windows-server-2003, subdomain, url-routing

[This is a dupe of a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322151/subdomain-rewriting-in-asp-net). But I don't know if it involves setting a server config. How do I implement something like http://why.does.my.head.explode.net/? I want to do something like ytmnd [where each url](http://kramerwii.ytmnd.com/) [is a different](http://crabmonkey.ytmnd.com/) user generated page. I might need something as simple as pointing to a directory so dirname.mysite.com will redirect to http_public/userGenContent/dirname/

Is this a server config? I plan to get Windows Server 2003 (for now) to host a ASP.NET project. How would I implement/setup a site like explode.net and ytmnd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is both network-, server- and application-related.

First of all, DNS: you need to have a wildcard record that maps *.yourdomain.com to the same IP address.

Second, web server: you need to define a wildcard site (or use the default web site, if the server does only that), so that IIS answers any request it receives whose host header ends with "yourdomain.com".

Third, application: you need to use a server-side application (written in your language of choice, ASP.NET is definitely ok) which parses the received request and shows the right content.